# Dual of a order continuous Banach Lattice $\subseteq L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, banach-lattices, orlicz-spaces

I have recently read a theorem in a paper (porbably) indicating that if we take a Banach Lattice $E \subseteq L^1$ with order continuous norm, then we can identify its dual $E'$ with another space $F \subseteq L^1$ by the identity

$$\ell_g (f) = \int fg d\mu, \text{ } \text{ }\text{ } \ell \in E', \text{ } g \in F$$

where $\mu$ is a finite (probability) measure. I know, that this is true for the $L^p$-spaces ($E = L^p$, $F=L^q$) and, more generalized, for Orlicz spaces with finite young function, but I can't reason why this should hold for *any* other Banach Lattice in $L^1$ with order continuous norm.

Is there a "basic" theorem I do not know? Can someone give me a hint or literature on this? Or does such a theorem not exist? I would be really thankful for an answer, since I am stuck on this for a longer time!

Comment: At least for Banach function spaces this is also asserted here: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Banach_function_space (search for "Köthe dual"). There are also references given, but they refer to entire books, so I didn't hunt down a specific theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds promising! I will dig into it.